# Subsonic Syntax Question (with GroupBy)

Tags: syntax, subsonic, group-by

Is there a way to do this :

```
SubSonic.Where filter = new SubSonic.Where();
filter.ColumnName = Region.Columns.Region;
filter.Comparison = SubSonic.Comparison.IsNot;
filter.ParameterValue = null;

SubSonic.Aggregate orderBy = new SubSonic.Aggregate(Region.Columns.RegionName, SubSonic.AggregateFunction.GroupBy);

RegionCollection regions = new RegionCollection().Where(filter).GroupBy(groupBy).Load();
```

The "GroupBy" part in the last line doesn't compile... (I'm using SubSonic 2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case there isn't a reason you need the old Where construct:

```
SubSonic.Aggregate groupBy = new SubSonic.Aggregate(Region.Columns.RegionName, SubSonic.AggregateFunction.GroupBy);

RegionCollection regions = new SubSonic.Select(groupBy).From(Region.Schema).Where(Region.RegionColumn).IsNotNull().ExecuteAsCollection<RegionCollection>();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Collections you can use `OrderByAsc` and `OrderByDesc` but they both only allow passing a  string as a parameter. And the `SubSonic.AggregateFunction.GroupBy`probably isn't what you want.

Try this instead:

```
var result = new RegionCollection().OrderByAsc(Region.Columns.RegionName).Load();
```